# Expose EF project to WCF service

Tags: c#, wcf, visual-studio, entity-framework-5

I have made a complex solution using EF5 (Lets call it EF5), this solution works perfectly fine and has a Logic.cs file,lies at the app_code, which has multiple functions that access , control and modify this solution, So far so good.

I would like that my business' clients to access these function and I'd like to expose these functions by using WCF.

The steps I did are the following.

1. Adding WCF project to the solution where the EF5 project is.
2. Writing "OperationContract"s for each of the functions I'd like to expose to my client.
3. Try implementing each of the functions by calling the EF5 functions.

The problem lies at the implementation, VS fails to recognize the logic.cs file , and therefore I cannot call the functions and expose my EF5 project to my clients.

I am new with WCF, obviously I'm doing something wrong here.

My question is, how do I expose EF5 project's functions, that lies in a .cs class , to WCF?

I believe that the major mistake that I made was that I didn't make a WCF project and added EF5 item to it, but I'm not entirely sure.

Here are the screenshots that displays my steps to add the EF5 Reference to the WCF project.

[image]

[image]

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Have you added a reference to the assembly in which your EF5 code resides in?

Comment: I believe that this is exactly what I struggle with, each time I looked for reference to add it only suggest the EntityFrameWork.dll, which isn't what i've been looking to, is there is a guide how to add a reference to EF project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a reference to your EF5 project from your WCF project.

You also need to make sure all your function to be called in Logic.cs are public.

Also make sure you are 'using' the namespace in which those functions are declared.

Comment: Can you link or demonstrate a guide which explain how to add a reference from EF project to WCF project ? each time VS only displays the EntityFrameWork.dll.

Comment: In VS, right click on the references in your WCF project, 'Add Reference'.  On the left, make sure you select Solution / Projects.  In there you should see listed your EF5 project.

Comment: Yup that what I was trying to do , but I don't see any project available, is there any wizard or guide that explain it step by step?

Comment: Thats strange, it is normally fairly apparent.  Have you got a screenshot of your solution explorer + the dialog you see when you try and add a reference?

Comment: I will modify my post with some pictures, BTW, my project is not a class library

Comment: I see!  It makes sense now.  Your EF5 project looks like a website.  This kind of project won't produce a DLL until it is published.  Either publishe the site, then reference the App_Code.dll produced, or consider changing the EF5 project type.

Comment: Is it possible to turn my EF5 project into a Project type instead of website, and if so, how do i do it? I already have all the EDMX , App_Data and web.config files at the website form of the project

Comment: Does it need to be a website?  Could it be a class library instead?  I have to ask as I don't know what your intention is for it.

Comment: it can definitely be a library , the thing is that I made it at the beginning as a website.

Comment: Create a brand new class library project in the same solution.  Copy the contents of your app_code folder into it, you can just drag it across in VS.  Make sure it builds, then just delete the olde web project.